# Trouble writing loop for secant method in python

Tags: python

I recently started learning python and one of the problems in my course was to program the secant method. I am having trouble reassigning the variables in the loop.

No matter how I write the while statement, I keep getting the division by zero error. I am assuming this is because my code is making the loops current x_1=x_0 and computing 
f(x_1)-f(x_0), rather than using the old x_1 for x_0.
My attempt:

```
G = 6.6741*10**-11
r_e = 6371000
r_m = 1737100
M_e = 5.9722*10**24
M_m = 7.3420*10**22
R = 3.8440*10**8
w =  2.6617*10**-6

def f(x):
    return (G*M_e)/x**2 - (G*M_m)/(R-x)**2 - w**2 * x

x_0=2*10**8
x_1=2.2*10**8

i=1

while i<=10 or 0.99 < x_1/x_0 <1.01:
    x_1=float(x_1-f(x_1)*(x_1-x_0)/(f(x_1)-f(x_0)))
    i = i+1
    x_0=x_1

print (x_1)
```

Error:

```
runfile('//myfiles/vj284/dos/python/Coursework q1.py', 
wdir='//myfiles/vj284/dos/python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-b33827a1b929>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('//myfiles/vj284/dos/python/Coursework q1.py', 
wdir='//myfiles/vj284/dos/python')

   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "//myfiles/vj284/dos/python/Coursework q1.py", line 20, in <module>
    x_1=float(x_1-f(x_1)*(x_1-x_0)/(f(x_1)-f(x_0)))

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... Copy and paste the text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting ... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am assuming this is because my code is making the loops current `x_1=x_0` and computing `f(x_1)-f(x_0)`, rather than using the old `x_1` for `x_0`.

Nope. It is because of your last line in the loop `x_0 = x_1`. Why do you overwrite `x_0`? Also, what is `y` for?

Edit: Since you have added text version, it is easier to fix your code. Simply use a temporary variable to hold "new" result. Also, change `or` to `and` AND add a condition to check for convergence (if method converged `x_0` will be the same as `x_1` and so the code will crash due to division by zero):

```
i = 1
while i <= 10 and 0.99 < x_1/x_0 <1.01 and abs((x_1 - x_0) / x_1) > 1e-15: :
    tmp = x_1 - f(x_1) * (x_1 - x_0) / (f(x_1) - f(x_0))
    i = i + 1
    x_0 = x_1
    x_1 = tmp
```

It is not obvious why do you have `and 0.99 < x_1/x_0 <1.01` in the loop condition. I think you should just remove it:

```
i = 1
while i <= 10 and abs(x_1 - x_0) > 1e-15 * abs(x_1):
    tmp = x_1 - f(x_1) * (x_1 - x_0) / (f(x_1) - f(x_0))
    i = i + 1
    x_0 = x_1
    x_1 = tmp
```

---

One last edit: In order to avoid the need for the temporary variable, I would rewrite the loop as follows:

```
for _ in range(10):
    if abs(x_1 - x_0) < 1e-15 * abs(x_1):  
        break  
    x_0, x_1 = x_1, x_1 - f(x_1) * (x_1 - x_0) / (f(x_1) - f(x_0))
```

Moreover, probably you should be checking on closeness of function values instead of its arguments: often, due to rounding errors, `f(x_1)` may be equal to `f(x_0)` even though `x_1 != x_0`. Or, you may want to check that `f(x_1) <= eps` indicating that the root was found.

Comment: Sorry y was another variable introduced in a previous attempt to see if I could work around it, ill edit my question and remove it. I did thought it would set x_0 as the old x_1, but I realise now it wont as x_1 has already been redefined. Making the statement before still doesn't help though.

Comment: just wondering why you multiply 1e-15 by x_1, wouldn't setting abs(x_1-x_0)< 1e-15, work just as well?

Comment: @VishalJain See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon _"Machine epsilon gives an upper bound on the **relative error**"_ (I just approximated machine epsilon with 1e-15 in the example). If the root of the equation is, let's say `x=1000` then the smallest number that you can add to `x` and get a different number will be approximately `x*eps` (~1e-12). That is why you need to multiply 1e-15 (epsilon) by `abs(x_1)`